# Touch on view behind fullscreen overlay

Tags: android, overlay, android-windowmanager, accessibilityservice

How i can perform [`AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.AccessibilityAction#ACTION_CLICK) or [`dispatchGesture`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService#dispatchGesture(android.accessibilityservice.GestureDescription,%20android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService.GestureResultCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) to a view that is behind fullscreen overlay touchable? this is possible with `AccessibilityService`? the goal is use the overlay to prevent user touch on screen, but without affect this action (touch) through `ÀccessibilityService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to be the bringer of bad news, but this is currently not possible with `AccessibilityService`. When having a full-screen touchable overlay view, the overlay doesn't allow touches to pass through it because it consumes all the touches. These touches don't propagate below the overlay.

Even if the device is rooted, you can't do this type of thing. If it could be done, it would be a serious security issue as apps that are malicious may present a different user interface to the user and may propagate clicks below the touchable window to perform different tasks.